# Unpickling StandardScaler (dumped from Python 2.7) in Python 3.5

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have trained Multi label classification model using https://github.com/inspirehep/magpie in Python 2.7.

Now I am trying to port the same in Python 3.5.
To port, the Word2Vec Embedding,Scaler and Keras Model are required to port to Python 3.5.

The word embedding, and Keras models are ported fine.

I am using StandardScaler.I have pickled it in Python 2.7 and unpickling it back in Python 3.5 
The unpickling is fine.

When I run prediction in Python 3.5, I am getting below error:

> sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: This StandardScaler instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.

Python 2.7:

```
scaler_path = 'path to file ......'
pickle.dump(scaler_obj, open(scaler_path, 'wb'))
```

Python 3:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler_path = 'path to file ......'
loaded_scaler = pickle.load(open(scaler_path, 'rb'),encoding='bytes')
```

> sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: This StandardScaler instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.

Comment: This is not recommended and may have unintended effects. A fitted `StandardScaler` only have 4 attributes learned (which are numpy arrays). You can just save those and set them in a new `StandardScaler`. Which version of scikit-learn did you use while saving? Is the current scikit-learn version same? Anways the error does  not seem related to that. Show the full stack trace of error and complete code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried using joblib dump and load It works fine.

Also, I have individually pickled 4 attributes of StandardScaler - mean_, scale_, var_ and n_samples_seen_ in Python 2.

Then Unpickled them in Python 3, It works fine.